# how tight winding of coils in solenoid reduces external magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism

My book says that the tendency to have zero field outside and a uniform field inside become more and more effective as the solenoid is more and more tightly wound.Can someone justify this statement.
I was facing problem for a point outside the solenoid as when I was calculating,magnetic fields in one direction became strong when coil is tightly wound from a stretched one.
[image]

Comment: PLease tell us **what** book this is, and if possible post a link or a scan of the pertinent page.  Also, how is the solenoid wound:  continuous helix, or counter-windings like in humbucker coils?

Comment: The books name is **Concepts of physics** by H.C Verma.

Comment: As in the image solenoid is continuous helix.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I hope you got it